# 'which python' and 'echo PYTHONPATH' give different directories, what does this mean?

Tags: 16.04, bash, python, bashrc

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with python 2.7. I'm trying to run python from a directory other than the one given by

```
which python
```

To this end, I put

`PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/myname/pybombs/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`

into my bashrc file. Now, `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python` and `echo PYTHONPATH` returns `:/home/myname/pybombs/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`.

Shouldn't they return the same directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man python`:

```
   PYTHONPATH
          Augments  the  default search path for module files.  The format
          is the same as the shell's $PATH: one or  more  directory  path‐
          names   separated   by  colons.   Non-existent  directories  are
          silently ignored.   The  default  search  path  is  installation
          dependent,  but  generally begins with ${prefix}/lib/python<ver‐
          sion> (see PYTHONHOME above).  The default search path is always
          appended  to  $PYTHONPATH.   If  a script argument is given, the
          directory containing the script is inserted in the path in front
          of  $PYTHONPATH.  The search path can be manipulated from within
          a Python program as the variable sys.path.
```

The `$PYTHONPATH` variable just specifies additional locations from which you can import modules. It has nothing to do with the location of the Python interpreter executable that you get as output from `which python`.